# What is the most complete and reliable open source C++11 IDE for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

I don't intend this to be an opinion question and I am deliberately avoiding the word "best" for that reason. To frame my question differently;

Is there a fully C++11 compatible Open Source and free (as in free speech, beer and lunch, not as in Express, Lite, Demo, etc.) IDE that provides stable syntax and error highlighting a la IntelliSense, that works out of the box with C++11, or at least with a minimal, easy to follow amount of work?

I am asking this question because I really like the VS2012 environment but have become frustrated with the lackluster degree of C++11 compatibility, and my license is due to expire anyway.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still a [shopping list question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/169187).

Comment: My understanding is that these questions are permissible as long as they are not based solely on opinion.

Comment: Yeah that's the direction I'm heading. Making a change is a big time investment though so I was hoping to get some feedback before I jump ship.

Comment: Since when do VS2012 licenses expire?  AFAIK only your subscription to receive future versions expires, but you remain licensed for whatever software was included in your bundle.

Comment: @ausairman Shopping-list questions are generally discouraged because they are open-ended. But in this case, I actually think your requirements for the IDE are specific enough to make this a pretty good SO question. Others, I am sure, will disagree.

Comment: I have an educational license for VS2012 ultimate, they expire.

Comment: Not sure why all the downvoting. SO is the perfect place to ask this question and it's no more opinion based than "vector vs array" or "which pointer should I use" questions.

Comment: "As in free speech, beer in lunch" is not opensource. Opensource is "free as in freedom". Having said that, if you need tool right NOW, your best bet will probably be to use generic text editor, such as vim (that is until microsoft adds better C++11 support to visual studio express which doesn't "expire").

Comment: I was hoping to get feedback on packages like Netbeans and Eclipse, which are complete IDEs. I've stayed away from text editors because I want an experience like VS, only, well... free.

Comment: @ausairman: In my experience, the best ide for C++ on windows is Visual Studio (looked for alternatives in the past, weren't impressed, gave up, because all opensource alternatives lack quality). Although project management is cumbersome, in conjunction with CMake/QMake it becomes almost perfect. Because VS doesn't completely support C++11, it means you'll have to either give up or wait. This is what you get for using cutting-edge language features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: it's not (mainly) the IDE that needs the C++11 Support, but the compiler. That being said - here are some options:

1. it is possible to integrate clang into VS2012 (check here: https://github.com/ishani/ClangVSx)
2. You can use any IDE that supports MINGW as compiler (Windows-GCC-Port) e.g. Eclipse CDT, QT Creator, Code::Blocks, DevCpp
3. You can use any IDE that supports Clang as compiler (e.g. Code::Blocks)

---

According to http://www.codelite.org/LiteEditor/ClangIntegration, you can configure codelite to use Clang for code completion vs. gcc. So depending on the IDE, the compiler might provide things like code completion.

Comment: How does a compiler relate the syntax/error highlighting? If I use a certain compiler, will the IDE get the information to highlight code from that compiler, or will the not match?

Comment: @ausairman: syntax highlighting is configurable in many editors. If you only need this much (without autocomplete, listing function parameters), then you don't need a specific IDE, just grab vim/emacs or anything generic.

Comment: @SigTerm: I want autocomplete, function parameters, etc. as well. Really I'm after the VS2012 experience with C++11, I realise this may not be a realistic request but I came here to find out if that's the case...

Comment: @ausairman it depends on the IDE. In VS2012 it does not come from the compiler - which sometimes causes a headache when the syntax-highlighting / error detection does not match the output of the compiler. In other IDEs it does (of course depending on the compiler)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the "[Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx)" update? It adds support for several features (most notably variadic templates) to VC11. The library is not there, and this compiler update is not considered production-ready, but I've found it to be great for working on my projects and using C++11 code till the final product comes out.

Also, I have used Qt Creator (quite independent from the Qt toolkit) for GCC-based C++11 development and it's a great IDE.